# SwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true) makes ListView jump to top

Tags: android, android-listview, swiperefreshlayout

I have a plain simple implementation of `SwipeRefreshLayout` that has a `ListView` as its child. The `ListView` presents a list of comments from a web API (paginated). Each time I load another page from the API, I use the setRefreshing(true) method on the `SwipeRefreshLayout`, which works as needed, except for the fact that this makes the `ListView` jump right to the top of the comments, even if you are 2-3+ pages in.

Is this the intended behaviour ? Because I couldn't find any hint about this. If so, is there any workaround in order for the `ListView` to not jump to the top ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looked through the method code of setRefreshing(). It doesn't effect the position of the scrollable child. Then it hit me that I was doing a selection on the list after the API call. So there's nothing wrong with the SwipeRefreshLayout. My bad.